# ServiceStack: Async version of 'HostContext.AppHost.ExecuteMessage'?

Tags: async-await, servicestack

[As answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56672465/178143), its enough to return a Task to make a ServiceStack service method async.

If I manually invoke a Service, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64566756/178143), I only have a non-awaitable `ExecuteMessage`, and no `ExecuteMessageAsync`. There is, in contrast, a method `HostContext.AppHost.ExecuteServiceAsync`.

- Is there a reason for the lacking `ExecuteMessageAsync`?
- I could do like `await Task.Run(() => ExecuteMessage(...))`, but it doesn't seem right to me.

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Why would you run a sync method in a new Thread just to await it again? i.e. What does the added inefficiency over calling the method normally suppose to achieve?

Comment: Well, no reason really, its just that the method was async and compiler warned. I can remove `async`and just use `HostContext.AppHost.ExecuteMessage(theMessage); return Task.CompletedTask;` instead, but, yeah, no reason really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExecuteMessageAsync` didn't exist because it's not needed or used by any of [ServiceStack MQ](https://docs.servicestack.net/messaging) providers. But I've just added Async versions of the `ExecuteMessage` APIs to both ServiceStack `AppHost` and its `ServiceController`.

This change is available from the latest v5.9.3+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Can I also ask if there is any news on this one: https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/5701744-provide-async-support-for-redis-client

Comment: @Ted Redis Async support is already available in v5.9.3+, access it with `using var client = redisManager.GetClientAsync()` from your Redis Client Manager or in your Service `using var client = base.GetRedisClientAsync()` in your `Service`. Requires .NET Core or .NET v4.7.2+.

Comment: Oh, great. Im getting some weird 503 errors, but I'll work em out and install 5.9.3. Thanks again.